# Dual Monitor Cursor Wrap Around (no edges)

Tags: gnome, xorg, mouse, cursor

Im using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I am using a laptop with a portable screen and I am wondering is it possible to make the mouse be "without boundaries"?

What I want to do is:

- **Mouse goes to left 2nd screen on the LEFT and wrap around to the RIGHT monitor on the right side** vice/versa. Is this possible? I have tried searching a lot but haven't found anything yet. I also tried Gnome Extensions to no avail.